# Gettting a Read-Only Filesystem Error in Android Studio While Attempting to Open an Sqlite File

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have written a program that connects to an sqlite file that contains bird data `bird.db` using JDBC.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.setProperty("open_mode", "1");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:bird.db", config);
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
```

I don't intend to write anything to the database, just read data from it. Now this code has worked for the several unit tests I wrote for it however when I try to run this on an emulator/phone I get this error when DriverManager tries to get the connection:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: opening db: 'bird.db': Read-only file system
```

Is there a way to work around this, or will I have to use another way of accessing the database? This is what my directory looks like for the [project:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leA7F.png)

Comment: You could use either the Android SQLite API, or Room, or any number of other Android object wrappers around SQLite. JDBC is ancient and is not used on Android. In terms of your specific problem, you are not providing a fully-qualified path to the database (particularly one to which you can read and write).

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. Would there be a way to gauge whether a path has read/write capabilities or to set that? I'm aware now that JDBC is old as all hell but it felt the quickest to learn to me.

Comment: "Would there be a way to gauge whether a path has read/write capabilities or to set that?" -- if you want to store the database in the normal spot for SQLite databases on Android, call `getDatabasePath()` on some `Context` (e.g., an `Activity`).